# How to open props.history.push() in a new window with a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, new-window

I want to open my Form Builder preview in a new window on button click.

I used the local storage method. I mean I stored the state in local storage then push to the new route and retrieve it. But I am not convinced about the method.

Currently, my **props.history.push()** is like this

```js
props.history.push({
  pathname: '/client/response',
  state: 'My Data objects are passed here',
})
```

What I want is, when I execute this line. it should open my next route in a new tab.
I can't use **Link** from **react-router-dom**. Because the state I am passing needs some preparation.

If it opens in a new window no problem at all.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't since each tab is isolated from another. When a new tab is opened, that tab is a new instance of the app. Local Storage or an API can share / display it on the new tab.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am just curious is there any way for it. Or is there anyone who has solved this problem

Comment: Aren't you already using Local Storage to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes I am, but I wanted to know is there any other way

Comment: Another option is to save state to your server